# Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History' while injecting React app into Chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-redux

I'm trying to inject React app into the Chrome extension. I have also connected it with Redux. Unfortunately, when I start the extension, I get the following exception:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:17 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://localhost:8000/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'chrome-extension://hajcaldemcjpnjmcjnocmiokajbbbfji' and URL 'chrome-extension://hajcaldemcjpnjmcjnocmiokajbbbfji/pop.html'.
    at http://localhost:8000/static/js/2.d6390d93.chunk.js:2:24695
    at Object.confirmTransitionTo (http://localhost:8000/static/js/2.d6390d93.chunk.js:2:22303)
    at push (http://localhost:8000/static/js/2.d6390d93.chunk.js:2:24606)
    at navigate (http://localhost:8000/static/js/2.d6390d93.chunk.js:2:48531)
    at onClick (http://localhost:8000/static/js/2.d6390d93.chunk.js:2:48088)
    at Object.m (http://localhost:8000/static/js/2.d6390d93.chunk.js:2:186427)
    at x (http://localhost:8000/static/js/2.d6390d93.chunk.js:2:186570)
    at http://localhost:8000/static/js/2.d6390d93.chunk.js:2:186716
    at T (http://localhost:8000/static/js/2.d6390d93.chunk.js:2:186802)
    at P (http://localhost:8000/static/js/2.d6390d93.chunk.js:2:187251)
```

I have no idea what is going wrong here... Thank you in advance for any help!

EDIT: I suppose there is some problem with react-router-dom...

Comment: The browser_action popup is a separate page with chrome-extension:// URL and it's not related to the web tabs. To access those you need a different thing: a content script. See [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and look for tutorials on using React inside a content script with `web_accessible_resources`.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for the answer, but I think it's not the case there. I use content script and generally the page loads, but when I try to perform some action, this strange exception happens. It looks like React cannot cooperate with Chrome extension

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) I can't really help so I have to keep guessing. You probably run this code inside an iframe that points to chrome-extension:// URL, not in the content script.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what was the reason... The problem is that I was using BrowserRouter from react-router-dom. Instead, I should use HashRouter.